# Django - Creating and update interval of function after which function executes

Tags: python, django, django-models, timer, scheduler

Problem - In a django project of PIZZA cafe.

After user ordered pizza , I scheduled a function which will execute after certain interval (say ***x seconds***) to inform user that pizza is now ready to be delivered.

But if pizza is ready to be delivered at less than ***x seconds***, ***How do I update the interval of scheduled function??***

***I need to identify each and every timer object uniquely so that I can edit or delete a timer object and schedule a function with new interval***

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you have already attempted to solve this problem? And an example of where that code failed with an explanation of the expected result? Your answer should provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that can be immediately replicated to help others help you.

Answer (score 0):

Set interval on some time for eg. 45 minutes, and if is ready earlier than just cancel it.

From [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#timer-objects)

Timer Objects
This class represents an action that should be run only after a certain amount of time has passed — a timer. Timer is a subclass of Thread and as such also functions as an example of creating custom threads.

Timers are started, as with threads, by calling their start() method. The timer can be stopped (before its action has begun) by calling the cancel() method. The interval the timer will wait before executing its action may not be exactly the same as the interval specified by the user.

For example:

```
import threading

def hello():
    print("hello, world")

t = threading.Timer(30.0, hello)
t.start()  # after 30 seconds, "hello, world" will be printed
```

class threading.Timer(interval, function, args=None, kwargs=None)

> Create a timer that will run function with arguments args and keyword arguments kwargs, after interval seconds have passed. If args is None (the default) then an empty list will be used. If kwargs is None (the default) then an empty dict will be used.

Changed in version 3.3: changed from a factory function to a class.

**cancel()**
Stop the timer, and cancel the execution of the timer’s action. This will only work if the timer is still in its waiting stage.

Comment: Suppose, there are two users in website. And I created separate timer objects o1 and o2 for both of them. In future if I need to cancel o1 object, then how will I uniquely identify o1.

Comment: store them in some collection  for e.g. dictionary as key use user id.